# How can I create a mesh of triangles made from the vertices of a polygon and contained within that polygon?

Tags: unity, c#, mesh, delaunay-triangulation

I'm trying to programatically generate a mesh, given the vertices of a polygon, which is contained within that polygon. For example, starting with these points:

[image: points solo]

I would want to generate a mesh similar to this:

[image: points preferred]

My first port of call would be a Delaunay triangulation, but having implemented this, I came up against the problem that this was *not* contained within the polygon, i.e. it produced a mesh like this:

[image: delaunay]

My question then is, is there either an algorithm which produces the desired result rather than the Delaunay result (because I can't find one online), or a modification that I can make to the Delaunay triangulation algorithm that will fix this?

I'm using the Bowyer-Watson algorithm, by the way. Thank you!

Comment: Presumably you reviewed common [polygon triangulation methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) and tried applying either ear clipping or monotone triangulation to your case? Where did you run into trouble?

Comment: That... completely escaped me. I'll take a look through it, thank you very much.